# Import issue when changing package name of a class

Tags: java, maven

I have two java projects (see below) with clashing package names, i am trying to rename packages to stop the confusion of clashing names. But I have come across issues.

**Project one:**

```
 com.example.test
 |_ ObjectOne.java
```

**Project two:**

```
 com.example.test
 |_ ObjectTwo.java
```

Now What I find strange is when *ObjectOne.java* is used in the class *ObjectTwo.java* **I don't get prompted to import the class.**

> **Question**: is this because the compiler thinks that ObjectOne.java is
>   in the current package of Project 2?

**Problem after package name change**

but...when I change the package name of project one to:

**Project one:**

```
 com.example.testing.test
 |_ ObjectOne.java
```

I now get a compilation error because there is no

```
import com.example.testing.test.ObjectOne;
```

> **Question**: is there any other way to solve this issue without having to
>   import the class everywhere?

Comment: Q1: yes, same package in different projects = same package. Understand "package" more like a "namespace" notion. Q2: no, you must import anything not belonging to the current package (nor java.lang)

Comment: @M_K I suggest replacing `new` with something other, else one might assume that you get the error because you use a reserved keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, No importing is required for the classes of the same package.

import is the normal way of adding dependent classes to your class.

Comment: `import` is not adding anything to a class, it is just a *namespace* used by compiler, that is, you are not forced to use the fully qualified name of the *imported* class(es) {no changes in compiled code}

Comment: thanks @CarlosHeuberger , agree with you that no need to use fully qualified name of the class if the class is imported. I tried to mean that without having the import statement(fully qualified name was not discussed yet), the class will not compile successfully. Do you mean that adding dependency is not the right way of expressing the need to import?